# Running a web application through apache tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

I have created a small web application in Netbeans. Now I want to run it on a Tomcat server.

Where should I put my webapplication directory in /webapps directory?

Comment: Do you have a `.war` file or just the classes?

Comment: Is it in the /dist directory or anywhere else?

Comment: If you have a proper web application project than the `.war` file should be in the `/dist` directory. You can move the `.war` file to Tomcat`s `/webapps`.

Comment: I already tried that process, that shows an error "HTTP Status 404 - Servlet Faces Servlet is not available"...

Comment: In the `.war` should be `/lib`. This directory should contain the Servlet Faces jars. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaxj.html

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans has templates for different types of projects, and when you select "Java Web Application" it creates build/test infrastructure (directory tree and ant build files) so that it can build war file which you can deploy into already running Tomcat server, or (if Tomcat server is properly configured in netbeans, as far as I remember you only need to tell netbeans where to find tomcat on your machine) it can start tomcat with you app deployed and it also starts browser on your app default page.

Answer (score 0):

what kind of application do you have? what you need to do depends on your applications requirements.

have a look at this [netbeans deployment description](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DeploymentOnExternalTomcatforNB6)

you can deploy manuelly by copying your webfolder with WEB-INF and META-INF folders plus your webfolders like markup, if any, also into your root folder, which would be webapps/YourProjectName

Comment: i did as you directed but that shows an error like " Servlet Faces Servlet is not available"....